# How to make one field automatically have the date-time of the last change of another field

Tags: nodes

I need to make one field have the date-time of the last change of another field in a drupal 7 content type.  I tried using a computed field but the calculation is complex and I am having trouble.  Is there an easier way to make one field reflect the date of the last change of one other field? 
thanks

Comment: Is there a time stamp field at the field_your_field or field_your_field_revision?

If yes it can be done but if no you may not do.

Comment: fields don't track the time they are altered - revisions are kept, but only as part of a nodes revision, but the timestamp is declared for the node, not the field - this means you will need to create a custom module that tracks changes and the times of those changes to the fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to save time in the field

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
 function jysk_reviews_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
    if ($node->my_changed_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] != $node->original->my_changed_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) {
      $node->my_time_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = time();
    }
  }
}
```